# GMake Echo Not Working Correctly, Dropping Backslash ( \ )

Tags: windows, gnu-make

I'm having issues getting GMake to work. It was fine as of late last week. I reinstalled my compiler to a new location on this machine and ran a quick (successful) build, but haven't built anything since.

Currently, output from GMake looks as follows

```text
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt Cleaning Build Folders IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt Cleaning Dependencies Folder...
```

...and ends with the following error

```text
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, del \F .\Output\dep*.dep, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
gmake: *** [clean_files] Error 2
```

The relevant portion of my makefile is as follows.

```make
@echo *********************************************
@echo ****      Cleaning Build Folders         ****
@echo *********************************************
@echo **
@echo ** Cleaning Dependencies Folder...
@$(REMOVE) .\Output\dep\*.dep
@echo ** Cleaning Objects Folder...
@$(REMOVE) .\Output\obj\*.o
@echo ** Cleaning Generated Assembly Files Folder...
@$(REMOVE) .\Output\asm\*.asm    
@echo ** Cleaning Release Folder...
@$(REMOVE) .\Release\*.elf
@echo ** Cleaning Finished
@echo **
@echo **
@echo *********************************************
```

I believe it may have something to do with my system configuration as this is the only system I've ever seen this type of problem on and the same makefile/setup is working for other users. Echo works fine on its own (IE when I type 'echo test' in a standard command prompt 'test' is echoed to the window)

Comment: That looks like you just don't have any files that match `.\Output\dep\*.dep` and `del` is erroring on that situation.

Comment: Notice that the path it's erroring on is ".\Output\dep*.dep" which is not what was passed to it. It would normally just say "Could Not Find ..." if del was not finding any files, right?

Comment: What is `@$(REMOVE)` supposed to do? It doesn't look like valid Windows batch.

Comment: Interesting. `del` returns a different error message when the glob fails to match and when a component directory doesn't exist. So that looks like you don't have the `Output` directory maybe. I do see the missing `\` in the error but I'm not sure what to make of that just yet.

Comment: @aphoria `@` is a make prefix for "silent" and `$(REMOVE)` is a make variable (here apparently containing `del \F` given the error output).

Comment: @EtanReisner Oops, I thought that was the batch file. My bad.

Comment: The call from the batch is pretty standard. I removed the tag as I don't believe it's really the issue

Comment: @EtanReisner The output directory ( .\Output\dep\ ) is present & accounted for, though the del command is looking for .\Output\dep*.dep for some reason. Nothing in it yet due to inability to build

Comment: Side comment. The reason your output looks so confused (and doesn't contain `**` is because the `**` is unquoted and the "shell" is expanding the globs into a file list. I'm assuming other people don't have that problem either? Are you supposed to be running this from cmd.exe instead of a bash/etc. shell? That would also explain the `dep*.dep` thing as bash/etc. would strip the backslash as a quoting backslash but cmd.exe would likely leave it alone.

Comment: I am running this from cmd.exe. Does GMake go off into its own shell or something?

Comment: Aha! I did a quick search on that and I found the answer. Thanks for the spark @EtanReisner. I added SHELL="cmd" to the call to gmake which forced it away from bash. I'll have to figure out how exactly the default got changed (again, everything was fine a week ago) but all is well now.

Comment: @EtanReisner If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it; you deserve some points. Kind of mad at myself for not seeing that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things in your output stand out as odd.

The make recipe lines:

```
@echo *********************************************
@echo ****      Cleaning Build Folders         ****
@echo *********************************************
@echo **
@echo ** Cleaning Dependencies Folder...
```

are producing the following output:

```
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt Cleaning Build Folders IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt
IDE LSL Lib MCAL_CA MCAL_DB Output Release Source build buildall.bat cleanall.bat compile_window.bat config_ca intro.bat project.pj test.txt Cleaning Dependencies Folder...
```

And the line:

```
@$(REMOVE) .\Output\dep\*.dep
```

is triggering an error that contains `del \F .\Output\dep*.dep`. (The assumption is that `$(REMOVE)` contains `del \F`.)

The first output oddity is explained by the shell expanding the `**` globs to the list of filenames.

The second oddity is explained by the shell removing an escaping backslash (i.e. `echo foo\*bar` produces `foo*bar` as output, etc.).

The makefile was clearly not written with either of those behaviors in mind.

Given that this is Windows it seems reasonable to assume that the `SHELL` intended for make to use is `cmd.exe` and not whatever shell (e.g. `sh`/`bash`) seems to be running the commands currently.

Confirming that that is, in fact, the case means that setting `SHELL=cmd.exe` in the makefile should fix the problem. The manual discusses selection of the shell on Windows in the [Choosing the Shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) section.